# mount error(13): Permission denied on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

I need help with mounting a **Windows** shared drive on **Linux**. I tried searching for the solution on Google and on this site, but unable to find one. I verified the user is having access to the shared drive.

NOTE: All the commands are being run with root.

```
sudo mount.cifs //domain.local/IT /mnt/share/ -o user=domain/username
```

Here is the error message i'm getting.

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Comment: When you're already logged in as root the don't need to use `sudo` for privilege escalation. - I'm not sure, but when you don't supply a password on the command line (using a credentials file is better in that regard), you won't be prompted to provide one right? And you probably need more credentials than only a username.

Comment: mount -t cifs -o username=<win_share_user>,domain=<win_domain> //WIN_SHARE_IP/<share_name> /mnt/win_share